# UISoundboard for iPhone on Xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [xcode 4.2 soundboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336708/xcode-4-2-soundboard)

Hi I'm creating a soundboard for my iPhone app but I keep getting errors etc in my code can you guys maybe edit it or do you known any better codes for a soundboard i am using Xcode 4.2 and I'm new so please be clear thank you for your time i really appreciate it!!

.h all fine i think no errors

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

}

-(IBAction)sound1:(id)sender;


@end
```

.m this is the one with errors

```
#import "ViewController.h"

//@interface ViewController ()


@implementation ViewController


-(IBAction)sound1:(id)sender {
CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"sound1" , CFSTR ("wav") , null);
}

uint32 soundID;
AudioservicecreatesystemsoundID(soundfileURLRef, &soundID);
AudioservicesPlaysystemsound(soundID) 



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
@end
```

thank you hope you can help me

Comment: @implementation viewController missing @end?

Comment: expected after method prototype
-(IBAction)sound1 {

Comment: expected identifier AudioservicecreatesystemsoundID(soundfileURLRef, &soundID);

Comment: Please implement @end in your implementation file. Also method prototype should be like this.
-(IBAction)sound1:(id)sender;

Comment: is there any chance you could edit it for me or just copy and paste than you ?

Comment: #import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h> in your header file.

Comment: please dude can you just edit it I'm lost??

Comment: AudioToolbox might not be the right framework for your needs here... You could probably make your life a lot easier by using AVFoundation; specifically, the AVAudioPlayer class.  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008067

Comment: ok thank you but I'm so new to this and do not no how to use them can you please please please just put the code up as a answer or edit mine thanks for your time.

Comment: @macserv the comment above is to you buddy thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AudioToolbox might be a bit too low-level for your needs here... You could probably make your life a lot easier by using AVFoundation; specifically, the [AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008067) class.

In your implementation:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString      *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sound1" ofType:@"wav"];
    NSURL         *soundURL  = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];
    NSError       *error     = nil;
    AVAudioPlayer *player    = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundURL error:&error];

    if ( ! player )
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
    }
    else
    {
        [player prepareToPlay];
        [player play];
    }
}
```

Note that I'm not doing any memory management here.  Also, if you need to play more than one sound at a time, you can either create additional instances of AVAudioPlayer, or you might check out the OpenAL library... there's a great wrapper for it [on github here](https://github.com/hollance/SoundBankPlayer).

Comment: hi there all i want is to play about 10 sound clips in each view controller do i just copy that code and place in the .m and what do i put in the .h buddy?? and memory management?? thanks for your time.