# xcode 4.2 soundboard?

Tags: iphone, ios

hi all i have been trying to create a soundboard for some time and i found this site is there anyone out there that can answer this question by putting up a fully working code for iPhone Xcode 4.2 thank you for your time.

heres my code but it has errors

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController 

-(IBAction)sound1 {
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"sound1", CFSTR      ("wav"), NULL);

    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

plus someone said to use av something please edit or upload code When answering I'm a beginner lol

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested the code you posted and it works very well as is - no errors here.

So you probably forgot to do one (or more) of the following things:

- include `AudioToolbox` framework into your project
- `#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>;` in your ViewController.m file
- add sound1.wav file to your project
- check that sound1.wav is really sound1.wav and not Sound1.wav or similiar
- connect your IBAction method to some event that really gets triggered